# Eclipse generating Javadocs just for the last class edited

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

The question is simple, and I think I'm the only one having this problem since nobody already asked this.

I am working with Eclipse on a big mess of software made from someone else, which passed by before even starting to write a documentation for it. So I am studying it and trying to write javadocs.

But with Eclipse, I wrote them for the first class and tried to generate them from project -> generate Javadoc, making sure I said to generate them for all the classes (ticked the box). The first class generated a working jdoc.
Then I commented the second class in the same way, run the generator again and now in the index.html there's only the second class. In the folder structure there are all the folders inside the "com" one, with the business and the ui ones, and the html files for all the classes. But I can't find them in the index page: the "all classes" frame only shows one class, and the "package" link is not even working.

I only want to generate jdocs for the public stuff, and the single html files are good for me. The problem is with the root one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *Project > Generate Javadoc*, then select which classes you want generate and

- check in Package level classes in first page (better usage for developers)
- press Next, then see "*Select referenced archives...should be generated:*", then search which classes/packages you want update, and check in again.
- after Next, check in your built-in browser seeing with "*Open generated index file in browser*"

Mine updates the javadoc in eclipse 2018-12.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. The pages get generated, but the index file does not link to any of them except the last one I edited.

Comment: Ok! If I pick each package in the menu the index get generated in the right way. That was the problem, it seems. Thanks!